# Disposing connection, command, adapter

Tags: c#, .net, using, oledbconnection, disposing

When I am querying the database from my c# code  I usually use something like this construction:

```
using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
using (var command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection))
using (var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
{///}
```

Should I actually use all this 'using' or it will be enough to dispose only connection and all related objects will be disposed too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it will be enough to dispose only connection and all related objects
>   will be disposed too?

No. Disposing connection will only dispose the connection object.

Generally it is a safe practice to dispose every object that implements `IDisposable`. *(One more thing, disposing `Command` object will not dispose the related connection object)*

Comment: But if these are nested using statements??

Comment: nested or other, It will only dispose its own object, not the other

Answer (score 3):

Using statement *only* dispose the instance that includes. It doesn't effect the other objects that *related* on that.

You use the right way in your case.

```
using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
using (var command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection))
using (var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
{

} // <-- Both connection, command and adapter disposed here
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no, this would only dispose your connection object. You therefore need all these `using`.

Long(er) answer: behind the `using` syntax, the compiler creates a scope in which the variable is created (the variable doesn't exist outside of the `using` scope) and the `Dispose` method will be called when exiting the `using` scope.

Therefore, if you don't create your `command` variable in a `using` block, the `Dispose` method will not be called and therefore the object won't be disposed. (unless you decide to call `command.Dispose()` yourself)